# How to get the passed object name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code, I'm interested in whether it is possible to get the name of the passed object inside the `useConf` function, namely `"container__wrapper"`, and not `"Object"`.

```
const conf = {
    container__wrapper : {
        style : {
            width : '100%'
        }
    } as Component,

    toolbar : {
        ui: "default"
    } as Component,
};

const useConf = (config: Object) => {
    return config.constructor.name; // Return "Object"
}

console.log(
    useConf(conf.container__wrapper);
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of the key or the value? If you want the key specifically 'container__wrapper', use `Object.keys()`

Comment: You can't, unless you're going to assign a name property to that object. JavaScript objects don't have a name nor a parent, all the objects are anonymous, and object properties (or variables) are only containing a reference to an object, they don't "own" the object they're referring to.

Comment: @Teemu great answer with explain, thanks.

Comment: But, you can figure this out given your code sample.

If you have access to your `conf` parent object from within the `useConf` function (it appears that you do), then you can check the `config` parameter for equality with the properties of conf.  Would be nice if I could add this as an answer :), but its closed.

```
const useConf = (config: Object) => {
    let confName = null;
    Object.values(conf).some([key, value]) => {
        if (value === config) {
            confName = key;
            return true;
        }
    }});
    return confName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can add a `name` property to your object for this purpose,
e.g:

```
const conf = {
    container__wrapper : {
        name: 'container__wrapper',
        style : {
            width : '100%'
        }
    } as Component,

    toolbar : {
        name: 'toolbar',
        ui: "default"
    } as Component,
};

const useConf = (config: Object) => {
    return config.name; // Returns "container__wrapper"
}

console.log(
    useConf(conf.container__wrapper);
);
```

Comment: Sadly, I wanted to get rid of passing the `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
const useConf = (config: Object) => {
    return Object.keys(config)[0] // Return "first key name"
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully.

Comment: You have to use Object.keys to get the key name of the object